# Deny Mac system using cached data when copy

Tags: macos, caching, copy-paste

I'm developing a encrypt & decrypt filesystem on Mac. I use `MacFuse` to realize this filesystem and mount it under a folder.

By doing this I can hook the open file method when the user are trying to open the encrypted file(such as `A.rtf`) under the mounted folder. Then I will decrypt `A.rtf` and generate a new decrypted file, let's call it as `B.rtf`. In the hooked open file method, I will return `B.rtf` file descriptor so that the user can open the decrypted file.

All worked fine, until I opened the encrypted file once and copied it. It seems the Mac system directly uses the decrypted cache data when doing the copy, so the decrypted content will be copied.

I tried add `fcntl(fd, F_NOCACHE, 1); fcntl(fd, F_NODIRECT, 1)` after `int fd = open([p UTF8String], mode);`, but it not work.

After some research, I know that there is some relationship between the `DesktopServicesHelper` process and the copy operation, so I tried don't decrypt the file when system process `DesktopServicesHelper` trying to open the encrypted file. But it still does not work, the Mac system seems to directly hand over the cache data to the `DesktopServicesHelper` process, then `DesktopServicesHelper` creates a new file in the copy target path with decrypted data.

So is there a way to tell the Mac system not to cache my data when I open a file?